# ¿Como iniciar el servidor npm?

Tags: npm

Intento empezar el servidor npm relatado con [este tutorial](https://serverjs.io/tutorials/spreadsheet/). Comprendí que tengaba que descargar npm y intento (o tengaba ?) que descargar npm y intento `npm start`. Sin embargo obtuvo errores al empezarlo.

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript$ sudo npm install server drive-db
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mike/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mike/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript/package.json'
npm WARN javascript No description
npm WARN javascript No repository field.
npm WARN javascript No README data
npm WARN javascript No license field.

+ server@1.0.18
+ drive-db@4.1.0
added 270 packages from 285 contributors in 5.126s

mike@mike-thinks:~/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript$ ls
index.js  node_modules  package-lock.json  views

mike@mike-thinks:~/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript$ npm start
npm ERR! path /home/mike/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mike/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mike/.npm/_logs/2018-11-24T09_20_12_336Z-debug.log
```

Sin sudo :

borré el carpeto y despues :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript$ npm install server drive-db
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mike/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mike/Documents/programming/tutorial/javascript/package.json'
npm WARN javascript No description
npm WARN javascript No repository field.
npm WARN javascript No README data
npm WARN javascript No license field.

+ drive-db@4.1.0
+ server@1.0.18
added 270 packages from 285 contributors in 17.772s
```

Comment: Estas instalando con sido y luego haces npm install probablemente no tiene permiso en la carpeta node_modules verifica eso creo que allí está el problema, agrega el log para ver qué dice

Comment: @JackNavaRow Muchas gracias. ¿Como puedo verificar que no tengo permiso en la carpeta node_modules? Pensé que eso sería suficiente

Comment: Borra la carpeta y ejecuta el comando sin sudo

Answer (score 1):

Antes de querer "levantar" el servidor de pruebas intenta con `npm init` para que cree el archivo package.json, ahi vienen las dependencias y los comandos que necesita tu aplicacion.

Aqui como utilizar el comando https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

Comment: Agrega los pasos que va a tener que introducir por ej: nombre, que archivo va a inicializar la aplicación etc.